# Can I pass in a "Type" as a function parameter?

Tags: types, interface, parameters, go, func

I'm trying to build a library that'll serve a struct Type as a RESTful resource automatically.

Here's what I envision it to look like in the calling code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sergiotapia/paprika"
)

type Product struct {
    Name     string
    Quantity int
}

func main() {
    // You need to attach a resource by giving Paprika your route,
    // the struct type and optionally a custom resource manager.
    paprika.Attach("/products", Product, nil)
    paprika.Start(1337)
    log.Print("Paprika is up and running.")
}
```

---

Inside of my library, I'm trying to create the Attach function:

```
package paprika

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Attach(route string, resource Type, manager ResourceManager) {

}

func Start(port int) {

}

type ResourceManager interface {
    add() error
    delete() error
    update(id int) error
    show(id int) error
    list() error
}
```

How can I accept any "Type" of struct? My end goal is to use reflection to get the type name and it's fields (this part I already know how to do).

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I did something similar where my function accepts `reflect.Type`, and when I call it, it looks like `attach(reflect.TypeOf(MyStruct{}))`. But can't you work around it with interfaces?

Comment: You could use an `interface{}` and then a type switch. http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch

Comment: @Kbo: The thing is I don't know what types there are going to be before hand. These should be detected at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach I found is:

```
func Attach(route string, resource interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(route)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(resource))
}
```

Then I can use any type I want:

```
type Product struct {
    Name     string
    Quantity int
}

func main() {
    Attach("/products", new(Product))
}
```

Results in:

```
/products
*main.Product
```

---

Unless there's a more idiomatic way to go about this, I think I found my solution.

Comment: AS already mentioned above, just use use an interface to pass the product instead of all the fancy stuff. That would be the idiomatic way to do it I think. Maybe the interface could have a function that returns to product type: GetProductType() Reflect.Type  (not sure what that would do)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use an `interface{}` as parameter type for your function. Then, it would be quite easy to know the *real* type of your parameter by using a [type switch](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch).

```
func MyFunc(param interface{}) {

    switch param.(type) {
        case Product:
            DoSomething()
        case int64:
            DoSomethingElse()
        case []uint:
            AnotherThing()
        default:
            fmt.Println("Unsuported type!")
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't know what types there are going to be before hand. These should be detected at runtime.

Comment: Event at runtime, those types must have been defined somewhere in your code. Isn't it possible to list all the allowed types in this type switch?

Comment: Unless you want to use your code as an external package of other projects, and still be able to use the specific types defined in them?

Comment: Yes that's my end goal - please see my answer here. I solved it and I'm actually using it from Paprika's package. :)